# UIView inside an UIScrollView did not refresh itself despite call of method "setNeedDisplay"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I've got an `UIScrollView` with inside, some views loaded from a xib file.

The `UIScrollView` loads only three `Views`. The current, the left one and the right one.

For exemple, I have one view at the left and one view at the right of the current `View`. If I scroll to the right, the `UIScrollView` will delete the view to the left, scroll to the right to the new current `View` and load the new view to the right of the new current `View`.

In addition, I have a button outside the `UIScrollView`. When I click on it, it changes the background color of the current view displayed on the `UIScrollView`.

It works well but sometimes, I don't know why, when I click on the button to change the background color of the view is well changed, but the view is not refresh so the user can't see the change of background color.

**The UIScrollView:**

```
container = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[container setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
[container setClipsToBounds:NO];
[container setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[container setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

**The method call when I click on the button to change the background color of the current view**

```
- (void)menuColor:(MenuPickerViewController *)controller didPickOption:(UIView *)button
{
    // Get the object containing the data of the product linked with the view.
    MyProduct *product = (MyProduct *)[MyProduct getProduct:[_slider getCurrentContentDisplayed]];

    // Get the the superview of the button sender to have an access for the attributes of this button (color selected, ...)
    ColorButtonMenu *colorView = (ColorButtonMenu *)[button superview];

    // Get the current UIView displayed in the UIScrollView
    MyView *myView = (MyView *)[self sliderGetViewWithID:[_slider getCurrentContentDisplayed] FromSlider:_slider];

    // I check with debugger, the color is well setted
    product.color = colorView.color;

    // "border" is a view in my xib that I want change its background color.
    IFPrint(@"myView.border backgorund color before: %@\n", myView.border.backgroundColor.description);
    [myView.border setBackgroundColor:[Utilities colorFromHexString:colorView.color]];
    [myView.border setNeedsDisplay];
    IFPrint(@"myView.border backgorund color after: %@\n", myView.border.backgroundColor.description);

    IFPrint(@"=== DEBUG ===\n");
    IFPrint(@"isMainThread ? : %i\n", [NSThread isMainThread]); // Always return YES
    IFPrint(@"myView: %@\n", myView); // Always return the address of a valid pointer
    IFPrint(@"myView border: %@\n", myView.border); // Always return the address of a valid pointer
    IFPrint(@"=============\n\n");
}
```

So, as you can see at the end of the method, I tried to call method `setNeedsDisplay` on the view loaded from a `xib` and the other view inside "border" but nothings work.
Moreover, my method is always called on the main thread.

Any suppositions ?

Thanks !

**Edit:**

Obviously, I have tested if the view return by sliderGetViewWithID is the correct view. All the attributes are well set. In my opinion it's truly a refresh problem.

Comment: is your menuColor method (always) excuted in the ui(main)-thread?

Comment: Yes, I think it is the case because [NSThread isMainThread] return always YES.

Comment: ahh didn't see the log statement. Sorry

Comment: After setNeedsDisplay can you log the background color of border?

Comment: Sure ! I modified a little bit the code of the method. See my edited message. ==================

viewPola.border backgorund color before: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.254902 0.698039 0.92549 1
viewPola.border backgorund color after: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.419608 0.419608 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :

After setting the background color of the view. I remove the view from the UIScrollView and I re add it inside the UIScrollView. It's a bit tricky but it works good !

```
[myView removeFromSuperView];
[myScrollView addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the view you're trying to set background color for is actually visible? I guess it might be offscreen so you see nothing happening.

You might want to trap that event by finding the intersection between scrollview's bounds and myView's frame. if there's no intersection, that means myView is not actually visible.

so the code is:

```
BOOL intersects = CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollview.bounds, myView.frame);
if(intersects == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"myView is offscreen");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I tested your code but this is very weird. Even when the change of background color work, the NSLog is displayed.